# passing variables from 2 different functions to one other function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am writing a javascript programme which involves passing values between functions. 
I have 3 functions called A,B and total and want to pass variable values from A and B into total.

```
function a() {
  var result = 10;
  total(result);
}

function b() {
  var result1 = 20;
  total(result1);
}

function total(r1, r2) {
  var x = r1;
  var y = r2;

  console.log(x + y);

  //remaining logic will go here
}

a();
b();
total();
```

For testing purposes i am only logging values from function a and b. But it is only getting value r1 from function a but fails for r2 from function b and says that r2 is not defined. I think it can only do one function at a time but I want it to get values from both a and b.

Comment: So you want to get a value from `a` and from `b` and use those values to call `total`?

Comment: As i have said, I want to get value from a and b and pass into total()

Comment: Look into the `return` keyword in JavaScript. It'll allow you to pull things from a function scope, and make it available to other functions via variables

Comment: make a and b return a value and then call `total(a(), b())`

Comment: I'd suggest running through some tutorials on JavaScript then. Learn about returning values from functions. It's a very simple concept once you get the hang of it. That's how you can use various functions to pass values to other functions.

Comment: Okay i will give it a go

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the variables at the top of your page then when they are used by your function they will be edited as your code runs through

Answer (score 0):

```
function a(){
  var result = 10;
  total.a = result;
 }

function b(){
  var result = 20;
  total.b = result;
 }

var total = {
    a: 0,
    b: 0,
    getTotal: function(){
        console.log(total.a + total.b);
    }
}

a();
b();
total.getTotal();
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ztdyyt0q/)